# use SSL / https on page

Tags: mysql, ssl, https

Example:

a.php

```
<html>
<body>
   <form action="b.php" method="post">
      <input name="username" type="text" />
      <input name="password" type="password" />
      <input type="submit" />
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

b.php

```
<?
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '{$_POST['username']}' && password = '{$_POST['password']}'";

if (....) {
    $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
    header('location: a.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

https should be used in which page?

https://example.com/a.php 
or 
https://example.com/b.php ?

Answer (score 1):

SSL is used so that your information is not transmitted in plain text. If you want your information to be transmitted securely.. BOTH as they both appear to use passwords.

It's a little difficult to tell as these pages don't look finished.

I'd worry more about possible SQL injection attacks on the second page.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is used to crypt information. So I would say B as you transfer user data.
However the best is to put your whole site in https if you really need encryption.

Do you know that only calling HTTPS won't work, you'll need to configure your server.

Comment: Yes, I know need configure server.

Because I have many pages use the login form
sublimt are pointing the same page (e.g. B.php)

But I do not want use https in each page.
So I want to make sure to only use https in the target page.
whether it is feasible?

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Then you may want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025012/ssl-how-and-when-to-use-it